# How can I turn column of one id into one value?(pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert rows of one ID into 'abnormal' column if there's one 'abnormal' in the type column.
For example, let's say I have this table.

| ID | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'normal' |
| 1 | 'normal' |
| 1 | 'abnormal' |
| 2 | 'normal' |
| 2 | 'normal' |
| 2 | 'normal' |

I want to convert this table into this because there's one abnormal in the type column of ID 1.

| ID | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'abnormal' |
| 1 | 'abnormal' |
| 1 | 'abnormal' |
| 2 | 'normal' |
| 2 | 'normal' |
| 2 | 'normal' |

That is, I want to keep normal only if there are all normal in type column. How can I do this in python way?

Comment: `df['type'] = df.groupby('ID').transform(lambda x: 'abnormal' if x.eq('abnormal').any() else 'normal')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['type'].eq('abnormal').groupby(df['ID']).transform(any), 'type'] = 'abnormal'
```

Or:

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df.loc[df['type'].eq('abnormal').groupby(level=0).transform(any), 'type'] = 'abnormal'
```

1. `df['type'].eq('abnormal')` creates a mask where each row is True if `type` is `'abnormal'` False otherwise
2. `.groupby(df['ID'])` (or `.groupby(level=0)` if `ID` is your index) groups the masked rows by `ID`
3. `.transform(any)` converts each group of masked rows to True if any element is True

*This post is updated after [@henry-ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925276/how-can-i-turn-column-of-one-id-into-one-valuepandas-dataframe/#comment128804053_72925302)*

Comment: The idea is good in theory, but `df['type'].eq('abnormal')` is a Series not a DataFrame and it does not have an ID column so you get a `KeyError: 'ID'`. Perhaps you meant `df['type'].eq('abnormal').groupby(df['ID']).transform(any)`?

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker for catching this. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see @BeRT2me's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925276/how-can-i-turn-column-of-one-id-into-one-valuepandas-dataframe/72925347?noredirect=1#comment128804081_72925276) for better and more performant answer.

Below is another way of doing it: (assuming `abnormal` and `normal` are the only unique values):

```
(
df.groupby('ID').
    apply(lambda x: 
          ['abnormal']*len(x) if 'abnormal' in x['type'].values else ['normal']*len(x)).
    reset_index().explode(0).
    rename(columns={0:'type'})
)
```

Comment: That is a __lot__ of processing for this task: new series creation, building a new numpy array per group, DataFrame reshaping, list building, index alignment... If you're going to build a new set of values per group `transform` is definitely the better approach like [this answer by Psidom](/a/68977846/15497888) or  [the comment by BeRT2me](/posts/comments/128804081).

Comment: @Henry Ecker I can't agree more. You are right.